# Couldn't find package "react" on the "npm" registry when creating a package

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

I am trying to create a new react project and used below command

```
npx create-react-app login
```

and installation fails, saying "Couldn't find package "react" on the "npm" registry".

Message:

```
Creating a new React app in C:\Amit\Code\Experiment\TestConsoleApp\login.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.7.0
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error Couldn't find package "react" on the "npm" registry.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this comm
and.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template --cwd C:\Amit\C
ode\Experiment\TestConsoleApp\login has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Deleting login/ from C:\Amit\Code\Experiment\TestConsoleApp
Done.
```

Comment: try removing .npmrc file from your pc. EG: rm ~/.npmrc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to remove npm registry

```
npm config delete registry
```

Answer (score 14):

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

...worked for me when having the same error

Comment: Please add why this solution works and I will upvote.

Comment: Simply noticing in my own setup through 3rd party packages that various registries can be added and over-written without realizing. This was a fix to get back to the default setup.